# Ws2tcpip.h not compiling

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, winapi

I'm making a bandwidth usage monitor using QT creator and every time I include Ws2tcpip.h I get a dozen of compilation errors like : error: redefinition of 'struct ip_mreq'

I only included the header file and still get many errors

```
#include "bandwidth_usage.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
Bandwidth_Usage::Bandwidth_Usage()
{

}

int Bandwidth_Usage :: get () {

}
```

Comment: IIRC you should not include `Ws2tcpip.h` yourself. It should be included as part of `winsock2.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The including `<windows.h>` and `<winsock2.h>` order makes a difference.
The following code works for me. Also see [the accept function example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-accept#example-code).

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
```